# Install Windows 7 on Mac using USB

Tags: windows-7, mac, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my Mac using a Windows 7 DVD.

I downloaded the ISO from [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/) and burned the image to a DVD. I then created a partition using Boot Camp for Windows on Mac and started the installation by inserting the DVD. Later when the Mac restarted, the Windows 7 installation begun.

I was then asked for the CD/DVD drivers. I searched Google about this but couldn't find any proper solutions. People say that the CD/DVD drivers issue is due to the downloaded ISO being corrupt or the DVD not being burned properly, but this is not certain.

As a result I've now decided I don't want to use a DVD for the installation. Is there any method for installing Windows 7 on a Mac using the ISO image downloaded, perhaps using USB?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to put a Windows 7 install on a USB drive formatted as NTFS and make it bootable.  There are plenty of tutorials all over the internet and even this site.  The problem is that Macs can't actually boot off an NTFS formatted USB drive.  So this won't work for you.

However, it sounds like all you need is drivers when installing from your existing DVD.  In that case, just put the drivers on a USB stick, insert it, and you should be able to browse to the drive  and load them through the Windows setup program.  Keep in mind that you need the fully extracted drivers.  If the individual inf/sys/etc files aren't on the stick, Windows setup won't be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan correctly states you can't boot from a Windows 7 Install USB due to various EFI boot limitations (read the FAQ on http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

As for your DVD, your ISO image is almost certainly corrupted or is not being burnt 100% accurately. To ensure the ISO image is valid, see if My Digital Life can provide a MD5 or SHA1 checksum for a valid image for you to compare against your own copy. To ensure a DVD is burnt correctly from an ISO always use the verification option if presented. This will do a bit-by-bit comparison of your burnt DVD against your hopefully valid ISO image.

I've had to redownload and reburn quite a few bad Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 DVDs in my time (both present the same error on corruption).